# Vue.js - Test a Plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js). I have a plugin, that looks like this:

**source/myPlugin.js**

```
const MyPlugin = {
  install: function(Vue, options) {
    console.log('installing my plugin');

    Vue.myMethod = function() {
    };
  }
}
```

I am trying to test this plugin using jest. However, I'm not settled on Jest. Still, at this time, I have the following in my `test/myPlugin.test.js` file:

**test/myPlugin.test.js**

```
const Vue = require('vue/dist/vue');
const MyPlugin = require('../source/myPlugin');

Vue.use(MyPlugin);

describe('MyPlugin', () => {
    let vm;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const template = `<div id="app"></div>`;
        vm = new Vue({
            template
        }).$mount();
    });

    it('should run', () => {
        Vue.myMethod();
        expect(true).toEqual(true);        
    });
});
```

When I run this test via Jest, I was expecting to see "installing my plugin" in the console window. However, I do not. Instead, I see:

```
TypeError: Vue.myMethod is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to setup a basic plugin with some tests. I'm not sure why this isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try `vm.myMethod()`

Comment: @randnum-1 Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not typically attach methods to the Vue object in this way. In most cases you add them to the `prototype`.

```
Vue.prototype.myMethod = function() {};
```

Then you would call it using

```
vm.myMethod()
```

```js
console.clear()

const MyPlugin = {
  install: function(Vue, options) {
    console.log('installing my plugin');

    Vue.prototype.myMethod = function() {
      console.log("method called")
    };
  }
}
Vue.use(MyPlugin);

const template = `<div id="app"></div>`;
vm = new Vue({
  template
}).$mount();

vm.myMethod();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Even when I use this approach is still doesn't work. Is there something specific that has to be done with the Jest test runner that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @user687554 Not that I know. Do you have a repo?

Comment: Argh... Figured it out. I was missing `module.exports = MyPlugin;` in myPlugin.js.